# Change all short_description field as empty

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes, importexport

I added 1000+ products with dummy short description as `short Description`. Now I would like to remove all short description.

I did export all products and made the column empty. Changed `short_description` as not required in attribute list.

Then I reimported the products. But still those values are there. How to remove short decription value for all products ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

go to

Admin > catalog > products

select all products

select action as update attributes

you have to check short description checkbox with empty text there.

save.

> please select short description as not required attribute.

re-index and clear cache after remove.

You can use this trick for any admin product mass Field update.

**I hope this will help you.**

Comment: Perfect Solution :-)

Comment: Good solution Denish ;) +v

Comment: if my answer solved your query than accept answer so it can be helpful to all stack-exchange buddies.

Comment: @denishvachhani accepted and +1 for quick info

Answer (score 4):

A ways,You can do this by code

Write a php shell script at  you magento root dir. Using  this script update this field vaue  to blank.

```
require_once  "app/Mage.php";
umask(0);
Mage::app('admin');

$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku',$sku);
$product->setShortDescription(' ');
/* quick save */
$product->getResource()->saveAttribute($product, 'short_description');
```